Help with pgfplots code
This is the code I currently have
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line width = .6]

  \pgfmathsetmacro\ac{3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ax{3.9}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ts{.75}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\tf{10}
  \begin{axis}[
  xmin=-3,xmax=3,
  ymin=-3,ymax=3,
  grid=both,
]

  \clip (-\ax+0.02,-\ax+0.02) rectangle (\ax-0.02,\ax-0.02);
  \draw[gray!50!black] (-\ax,   0) -- (\ax,0  );
  \draw[gray!50!black] (   0,-\ax) -- (  0,\ax);
  \fill[blue!50,       domain=   -\tf:0, samples=100, smooth, variable=\t] plot ( {\ac*\t*\t/(1+\t*\t*\t)}, {\ac*\t   /(1+\t*\t*\t)}) -- cycle;
    \fill[red!50,       domain=   \tf:0, samples=100, smooth, variable=\t] plot ( {\ac*\t*\t/(1+\t*\t*\t)}, {\ac*\t   /(1+\t*\t*\t)}) -- cycle;
  \draw[red!75!black, domain=-\ts:\tf, samples=100, smooth, variable=\t] plot ( {\ac*\t   /(1+\t*\t*\t)}, {\ac*\t*\t/(1+\t*\t*\t)});
  \draw[red!75!black, domain=-\ts:\tf, samples=100, smooth, variable=\t] plot ( {\ac*\t*\t/(1+\t*\t*\t)}, {\ac*\t   /(1+\t*\t*\t)});
    \draw[green!50!black] (3,-4) -- (-3,2);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

I would like to "split" the blue-shaded area into 3 parts - in particular:

Let $A_1$ be the area enclosed by the upper-left wing, the asymptote and the horizontal axis,
$A_2$ be the area enclosed by the asymptote, the horizontal and vertical axes, and
$A_3$ be the area enclosed by the bottom-right wing, the asymptote and the vertical axis. How can I do this?


Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ and which packages need to be loaded in order to get your code snippet to compile.

Just out of idle curiosity: Why is this posting tagged biblatex?

welcome! the vast majority of people want help with latex code. please make your title specific to help people searching for questions to answer or answers to questions.

can you complete your snippet so we can compile it?

Just so people know, this uses pgfplots as the sole package. I think it could be more clear in specifying the regions to be shaded, but I think I can get an idea from your description. I think it would be really helpful to include a picture of the output, and draw the regions you want to be shaded on it.

I am not 100% sure that I understand correctly what you want to achieve, but you could save the path and use it several times by clipping it:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line width = .6]
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ac{3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ax{3.9}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ts{.75}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\tf{10}
  \begin{axis}[
  xmin=-3,xmax=3,
  ymin=-3,ymax=3,
  grid=both,
]

  \clip (-\ax+0.02,-\ax+0.02) rectangle (\ax-0.02,\ax-0.02);
  \draw[gray!50!black] (-\ax,0) -- (\ax,0);
  \draw[gray!50!black] (0,-\ax) -- (0,\ax);
  \path[domain=-\tf:0, samples=100, smooth, variable=\t, save path=\pathA] 
    plot ({\ac*\t*\t/(1+\t*\t*\t)}, {\ac*\t/(1+\t*\t*\t)}) -- cycle;

  \begin{scope}
    \clip (-\ax+0.02,\ax+0.02) rectangle (0,0);
    \fill[blue!50!red] [use path=\pathA];
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}
    \clip (-\ax+0.02,-\ax+0.02) rectangle (0,0);
    \fill[blue!50] [use path=\pathA];
  \end{scope}
  
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (\ax+0.02,-\ax+0.02) rectangle (0,0);
    \fill[blue!50!green] [use path=\pathA];
  \end{scope}
  
  \fill[red!50, domain=\tf:0, samples=100, smooth, variable=\t] 
    plot ({\ac*\t*\t/(1+\t*\t*\t)}, {\ac*\t/(1+\t*\t*\t)}) -- cycle;
  \draw[red!75!black, domain=-\ts:\tf, samples=100, smooth, variable=\t] 
    plot ({\ac*\t/(1+\t*\t*\t)}, {\ac*\t*\t/(1+\t*\t*\t)})
    plot ({\ac*\t*\t/(1+\t*\t*\t)}, {\ac*\t/(1+\t*\t*\t)});
  \draw[green!50!black] (3,-4) -- (-3,2);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


